# Sensors for a Validation Research

Tags: sensors, wireless, gps

I've been searching for wireless sensors that could track the following metrics:

- Location (GPS)
- Heart Rate
- Head Movement
- Length of Steps
- Skin Conductance
- Pavement location
  (relative location compared to the walking lane, needs to be more accurate than GPS, to measure distance from cars, other walkers..)

I was thinking of the [E4 Wristband](https://www.empatica.com/en-gb/research/e4/), with additional cameras to measure head movement and pavement location.

Any recommendation to other sensors I should consider? Maybe a group of 3-5 sensors that could carry all functions?

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure this is the best SE site to ask if you're *just* searching for specific sensors. There doesn't seem to be an IoT angle to it.

Comment: Yes, it does seem more suited to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  As to head movement, I remember 5 years or more ago finding a few circa $100 "brain wave monitors" and ***think*** that I recall them detecting head movement, so you might want to Google in that direction.  Power supply is going to be  factor here

Comment: See, for instance https://www.overdriveonline.com/fatigues-fast-track-body-language-wearable-monitor-makers-see-inroads-in-trucking-industry-detecting-fatigue/

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The project is IoT related, that's why I used this forum, but perhaps I should pop the questions in hardware-related networks.

Comment: See if you get any help here. If not, delete this question, and ask again over there. Meanwhile, Google for `crowdsupply health monitor`. I Saw a programmable BLE on Crowd Supply yesterday which had heart rate and steps, maybe more (I can’t dig it out, as I am at work). Also look at Kick Starter and IndieGogo, as that’s where you will find emerging new tech which might be of use. I doubt that you will get it all in one device, but a few combined might do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Heart Rate Sensor](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1540.html)
The heart rate sensor is based on photo phlethysmography based on blood absorbing light, this is low cost sensor with reasonable accuracy

[GPS Module](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-GPS-p-959.html)
GPS module has an accuracy of 2 - 3 meters, can also be used to measure speed, in combination of the below sensor (accelerator, gyro and magneto meter) accuracy can be increased

[Head Movement, Steps Length, Direction](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/9-axis/mpu-9250/)
Attaching the sensor to head can measure the angular acceleration and along with magneto meter can detect the direction of rotation

[Skin Conductance GSR Sensors](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-GSR_Sensor/)
The galvanic skin response refers to changes in sweat gland activity that are reflective of the intensity of our emotional state, otherwise known as emotional arousal. The sensor can measure the magnitude not the mood like (happy, sad, etc) but can detect the intensity

[Microwave Doppler Radar Wireless Motion Sensor](https://robu.in/product/hb100-microwave-doppler-radar-wireless-motion-sensor/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5rbsBRCFARIsAGEYRwfrt1Ubmdsh0gzPvr3z_oabAsAwDphakODGAPz0YaDRhCBuoAyUCRgaAil-EALw_wcB)
Low distance (20 meters range) obstacle measurement sensor to detect objects

Hope this helps